# HttpClient - setting a "global" socket timeout, and a separate timeout per request

Tags: java, apache-commons-httpclient

With HttpClient, I am setting the default socket/connection timeout with the following:

```
HttpParams params = new BasicHttpParams();

HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(params, 30000);
HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(params, 30000);

mClient = new DefaultHttpClient(connectionManager, params);
```

I'm wondering if I can override these values on a per request basis?

Edit: Would this work?

```
HttpParams params = req.getParams(); // req is an HttpRequest object
HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(params, 60000);
HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(params, 60000);
```

I tried it, and it seems to, but it's hard to test/create a situation where a timeout will occur.

Comment: Which version of HttpClient are you using?

Comment: 4.0.x - the version in Android

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using HttpClient 4.0 you could do this :

```
mClient = new DefaultHttpClient(connectionManager, params) {
  protected HttpParams determineParams(HttpRequest req) {
    //Fill in your impl here
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can simply set those parameters on the request object. For details see:
http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/tutorial/html/connmgmt.html#d4e391

Comment: Looks like the URL is now: http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/tutorial/html/connmgmt.html#d4e391